# Postgres - testing database connection in bash

Tags: bash, postgresql, docker, coreos

I wonder if there is an alternative to the psql command to test the connection to a postgresql database using bash.

I'm setting up a Core OS cluster and have a side service which should perform the equivalent of `psql 'host=xxx port=xxx dbname=xxx user=xxx'` every minute to determine if the service is running, and more important, if one can connect to it using the given parameters).

I cannot install postgres directly on Core OS. The command usually used in Core OS is something like `curl -f ${COREOS_PUBLIC_IPV4}:%i;`. But it tells only if the service itself is running on the given port, without any access check.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: _I cannot install postgres directly on Core OS_: so what can you install?

Comment: Docker containers... so basically the options seem 1. do the job in bash or 2. run a container (which is quite suboptimal for checking the availability of other units)

Answer (score 132):

`pg_isready` is a utility for checking the connection status of a PostgreSQL database server. The exit status specifies the result of the connection check.

It can easily be used in bash. [PostgresSQL Docs - pg_isready](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/app-pg-isready.html)

**Example Usage:**

```
pg_isready -d <db_name> -h <host_name> -p <port_number> -U <db_user>
```

**Installation**

```
sudo apt install -y postgresql-client
```

**Exit Status**

`pg_isready` returns the following to the shell:

```
  0 - if the server is accepting connections normally, 
  1 - if the server is rejecting connections (for example during startup), 
  2 - if there was no response to the connection attempt, and 
  3 - if no attempt was made (for example due to invalid parameters).
```

**Notice**: `man pg_isready` states: *It is not necessary to supply correct user name, password, or database name values to obtain the server status; however, if incorrect values are provided, the server will log a failed connection attempt.*

Comment: This should be the accepted answer in my view @Raphael

Comment: @FreeSoftwareServers an example : `pg_isready -d dbname -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres`

Comment: @Laurent The example was already added to the answer on Apr 23, but thank you anyway.

Comment: He says: ```I cannot install postgres directly on Core OS```. So, he cant use any postgres utility.

Comment: @NamGVU it's a bad answer not answering the question at all

Answer (score 18):

you can write a simple connection script in your language of choice.

hopefully your Core OS system has one of perl, php, python, ruby, etc installed

here is one in python:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.4
#
import psycopg2
try:
    db = psycopg2.connect("dbname='...' user='...' host='...' password='...'")
except:
    exit(1)

exit(0)
```

now your cmdline looks like this

```
python psqltest.py && echo 'OK' || echo 'FAIL'
```

Comment: Thank you David. Unfortunately, none of these language is installed on CoreOs (which is readonly...)

Comment: This does not answer the question of how to test from BASH.

Comment: Agree with Steven, secondly i don't have psycopg2 in my docker container

Answer (score 3):

For a pure bash implementation, you could use:

```
DB_HOST=localhost DB_PORT=5432 bash -c 'printf "" 2>>/dev/null >>/dev/tcp/${DB_HOST}/${DB_PORT}'
```

which will return `0` if the database is ready to accept connections, otherwise `1`.

Note: this will only test the database readiness, but it does not perform any authentication.

I use it inside docker-compose as an entrypoint to wait for the db to be ready before starting the service (`depends_on` only checks if the container is alive).

For example:

```yaml
    # wait for db to accept connections, then start the process
    entrypoint: |
      bash -c '
        until printf "" 2>>/dev/null >>/dev/tcp/db-host/5432;
          do sleep 1;
        done;
        target/release/app; # execute application
      '
```

Comment: This command check if port $DB_PORT is open on $DB_HOST and if something is listening on this port. This can not validate that a database is running and that we can connect to it.

Answer (score 2):

You can build a simple container that extends the first (to conserve disk) to perform the check. For example:

```
FROM postgres

ENTRYPOINT [ "psql", "-h", "$POSTGRES_PORT_5432_TCP_ADDR",  "-p", "$POSTGRES_PORT_5432_TCP_PORT" ]
```

If you're using a different image than `postgres`, of course use that one. You can use pretty much any command line you like and still check exit codes from bash on the CoreOS host:

```
#!/bin/sh
if ! docker run --link postgres:postgres psql --command "select * from foo;" ; then
   # Do something
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

To see the connection information in PSQL Shell (psql) use `\c`

Comment: postgres=# \c conninfo
FATAL:  database "conninfo" does not exist

Comment: @RafisGaneev , just `\c` without `conninfo`

Comment: I guess `conninfo` was just a name of sample database.

Comment: @saulius2. Good time to edit my post.